# regular expression to extract tokens from block of text

Tags: regex, logstash-grok

I have following block of text retrieved from a log file

> SELECT statement with ID: AE12400  SELECT /*+ ALL_ROWS */
>   T1.CONFLICT_ID,        T1.LAST_UPD,        T1.CREATED,
>   T1.LAST_UPD_BY,        T1.CREATED_BY,        T1.MODIFICATION_NUM,
>   T1.ROW_ID,        T1.DFLT_LIC_FLG,        T1.NAME,        T1.VAL,
>   :1     FROM          SIEBEL.S_LST_OF_VAL T1     WHERE
>   (T1.ACTIVE_FLG = :2 OR T1.ACTIVE_FLG IS NULL) AND        (T1.TYPE = :3
>   AND T1.BU_ID IS NULL)     ORDER BY        T1.TYPE, T1.ORDER_BY, T1.VAL
>   Bind variable 1: ,,,SADMIN,00000002579c129c:0,,List Of Values
>   (Internal),  Bind variable 2: Y  Bind variable 3: ZERO_DTIME_MODE
>   ***** SQL Statement Execute Time: 0.028 seconds *****    3 row(s) retrieved by ID: AE0EF18

I need to get following tokens out of this block

```
Statement Id : AE12400 

SQL_Query: SELECT /*+ ALL_ROWS */ 
        T1.CONFLICT_ID, T1.LAST_UPD, T1.CREATED, 
        T1.LAST_UPD_BY, T1.CREATED_BY, T1.MODIFICATION_NUM, 
        T1.ROW_ID, T1.DFLT_LIC_FLG, T1.NAME, T1.VAL, 
        :1 FROM SIEBEL.S_LST_OF_VAL T1 WHERE 
        (T1.ACTIVE_FLG = :2 OR T1.ACTIVE_FLG IS NULL) AND (T1.TYPE = :3 AND T1.BU_ID IS NULL) ORDER BY T1.TYPE, T1.ORDER_BY, T1.VAL

Bind Variable : [",,,SADMIN,00000002579c129c:0,,List Of Values (Internal)","Y","ZERO_DTIME_MODE"]

SQL Time: 0.028

SQL Rows: 3
```

I have come up with following regular experssion so far to extract the statement, time & rows

```
SQL Rows : \s\d{1,4}\s
SQL Time: \d{1,3}\.\d{1,4}
Statement Id: (ID:)(\s\w+)
```

But I am not sure how to extract the SQL along with Bind Variables from the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current patterns are not precise as they may match another sub-strings that are not expected ones. Hence, I'll go to provide all needed expressions:

SQL rows:

```
\d{1,4}(?=\s*row)
```

Query running time:

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?=\s*second)
```

Statement ID:

```
ID:\s*(\w+)
```

SQL statement (`m`: dot matches newlines):

```
(?m)ID:\s\w+\s(.*?)(?=Bind variable)
```

Bind variables:

```
(?m)Bind variable\s*\d+:\s*(.*?)(?=Bind variable|$)
```

For bind variables you should work with a `matchAll()` or `findAll()` similar method in your programming language. [[Live demo](http://rubular.com/r/pVFPbu8Ukb), look at *Match groups* block]

Comment: The experssion that you have given for Bind variables is working on the link given by you but when I try the same thing with regex101.com it shows only one match. I will try this with logstash and see if it works and mark that as answer after that. Also thanks for providing the rest of the expressions.

Comment: For regex101, since engines are different, you should use `g` flag. @Neel

Comment: when I use g flag then it matches everything after bind variables till the end of statement. It seems the logstash regex engine is same as regx101 as in logstash also I am only able to get first Bind Variable statement

Comment: I'm not familiar with logstash but as I said you should look for a method to find all matches (since as default they would stop at first match) As per regex101, check *Match Information* block: https://regex101.com/r/oH7fS1/1 @Neel

Comment: If there is newline character after the Bind Variable statements then it works perfectly but I have complete block as single string. Updated your example https://regex101.com/r/oH7fS1/2

Comment: Also you should know that, you have to use same regex flavor tester as your current programming language. Because behaviors differ. For example, in oniguruma (your current regex engine) `m` modifier means *dot matches newlines* while in PCRE (regex101 example) `m` means *`^` and `$` match new lines.* @Neel

Comment: You were right the problem was that I as using the wrong engine. This is the final string that gave me the desired Bind variable string (?m)Bind variable\s*\d+:\s.*(?=\s{1,5}\*{1,5} SQL). Marking your response as answer as it came closest to me finding the answer.

Answer (score 0):

These could be cleaned up; they're not very efficient as they are. But this should head you in the right direction.

SQL_Query: `SELECT(?! statement with ID)[\W\w]*?(?=Bind variable \d)`

If you're regexing a whole log with more than one of those text blocks, you'll have to get all the bind variables first, and then each one taken from that. Otherwise, you can skip that step.

Find bind vars: `Bind variable \d+:[\W\w]*?(?=\s+\*\*\*\*\*)`

Extract vars: `Bind variable \d+:\s*([\W\w]*?)(?=Bind variable)`

Also there could be problems if, for example, there is the text "Bind variable" within your SQL Query... But it would be difficult to get 100% on that, and it's unlikely there would be such things mixed into the other parts of the log, I'm guessing.